# Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known

Tags: npm, package.json, npm-publish

Started receiving the error; `Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known`  after updating our npm version from `6.14.14` to `8.1.2` when trying to run `npm publish` against our **private** package to our **private** registry.

Our `package.json` is configured with `"private": true` and we have also configured our private registry in a local `.npmrc` file on the build server.

```
> npm publish dist/{{project}}
npm ERR! code 128
npm ERR! An unknown git error occurred
npm ERR! command git --no-replace-objects ls-remote ssh://git@github.com/dist/{{project}}.git
npm ERR! ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
npm ERR! fatal: Could not read from remote repository.
npm ERR! 
npm ERR! Please make sure you have the correct access rights
npm ERR! and the repository exists.
```

Why is this updated version of npm trying to publish to github.com?

Switching the build agent target back to the `6.14.14` install does not try to publish out to github.com and successfully publishes it to our private registry.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I just had that issue after migrating to Node 16 & npm 8 :

Per [this issue](https://github.com/npm/cli/issues/3993), the publish path needs a trailing slash.

So `npm publish dist/myProject` should be `npm publish dist/myProject/`